# How do I declare an array in R?

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to declare an array in R, something logically equivalent to the following Java code:

`Object[][] array = new Object[6][32]`

After I declare this array, I plan to loop over the indices and assign values to them.

Comment: `array(dim = c(6, 32))`. This fills it with `NA`'s, if you prefer zeros, `array(0, dim = c(6, 32))`

Comment: @RuiBarradas: why do you not add this as answer? Go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with what you are planning on doing in R, but loops are generally not recommended. I would say this is especially true when you don't know the length of the output.

You might want to find a "vectorized" solution first and if not, then using something in the [apply](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html) family might also be helpful

Disclaimer: I am certain there is more nuance to this discussion based on what I have read, so I don't want to claim to be an expert on this subject.